# how to tell if a point is within a certain radius from a polygon using geopandas?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have two files(.shp): the first containing cities as polygons and the second containing parks as points. I have to find how many parks are there in a given distance from a city.
I was thinking using buffer to extend the area of the polygon by the distance and then iterate over the polygons and check which park(point) is in this area. Any ideas on how should I proceed, please?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

cities_shape = gpd.read_file('geo_cities_f.shp')
parks_shape = gpd.read_file('geo_parks_f.shp')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,14))
cities_shape.buffer(0.002).plot(ax = ax, color='blue', edgecolor='black')
parks_shape.plot(ax = ax, color='red', edgecolor='black')

cities_shape['geometry'].buffer(0.0004).plot(figsize=(14,14))

**parks(points)**
    SRID    geometry
    0   SRID=4326   POINT (34.79473 32.07580)
    1   SRID=4326   POINT (34.80149 32.12502)
    2   SRID=4326   POINT (34.76660 32.07581)
    3   SRID=4326   POINT (34.78834 32.06583)
    4   SRID=4326   POINT (34.78338 32.06643)

**polygons**
SRID    geometry
0   SRID=4326   POLYGON ((34.80707 32.05355, 34.80704 32.05350...
1   SRID=4326   POLYGON ((34.80707 32.05355, 34.80704 32.05350...
2   SRID=4326   POLYGON ((34.80712 32.05342, 34.80713 32.05341...
3   SRID=4326   POLYGON ((34.80712 32.05342, 34.80713 32.05341...
4   SRID=4326   POLYGON ((34.80712 32.05337, 34.80715 32.05336...
```

Comment: What would success look like to you?

Comment: success for me is to count how many points (and which) are in a certain distance of each polygon
what I did was setting a buffer for each polygon and then check if a point is within this area. it worked but was too slow. is there any better way?

Comment: You might try changing the `resolution` argument of the buffer. It sounds like your data is large, and pandas is the bottleneck here. In that case, you could try the dask flavor of geopandas (https://github.com/geopandas/dask-geopandas). You could roll your own code out instead of relying on geopandas if you want complete control of your work.

Comment: thanks, changed it to 1 and it help a bit

Answer (score 0):

You comment that your approach was too slow. After buffering, how did you check if there was a point inside a polygon? You should do this part using a spatial tree instead of looping over each geometry if you hadn't done so already, in order to make it more performant. After buffering, use geopanda's <strike>intersect</strike>  [spatial join](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html) or manually build a tree using [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#str-packed-r-tree).

Comment: after buffering I have used spatial join. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: In your post, you mention: "buffer to extend the area of the polygon by the distance and then iterate over the polygons" - you should do the spatial join in a single operation. 
Also make sure you use an appropiate buffer resolution like the other commenter has noted.

Comment: thank you, I haven't explained myself good enough, after the buffer I perform sjoin like this:  points_within = geopandas.sjoin(
        df_points, df_polys)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your data is large, and pandas is the bottleneck here. Try using `dask-geopandas`, which uses dask dataframes instead of pandas dataframes. Just install the package with `pip install dask-geopandas` then change the line

```
import geopandas as gpd
```

to

```
import dask_geopandas as gpd
```

Comment: thank you. eventually I'm using 'read_postgis' and it seems it is not in 'dask_geopandas'

Comment: Unfortunately, that feature is still in development (https://github.com/geopandas/dask-geopandas/issues/15). Maybe you can switch back to geopandas after the memory bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `geopandas.sjoin_nearest()` with the `max_distance` argument that you choose.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

cities_shape = gpd.read_file('geo_cities_f.shp')
parks_shape = gpd.read_file('geo_parks_f.shp')

park_city_pairs = parks_shape.sjoin_nearest(cities_shape, max_distance=1) #whatever distance you choose

number_of_parks = len(park_city_pairs['park_id'].drop_duplicates())
```

I'm assuming your `geo_parks_f.shp` has an identifier column for every park like `park_id`

Comment: thank you but i need to determine how many parks are there, within a given distance, in each city (parks can be related to more than one city)